# using shm_open to copy integers from parent process to child process

Tags: c, shared-memory

I am trying to copy integers from a parent process to a child process. Many questions of this nature are redirected towards using a different IPC method. That will not work for my case. The solution MUST use `<sys/shm.h>`. This a part of a much larger program. I am initializing the size, pointer, pid, and memory name like so:

```
          const int SIZE = 4*sizeof(int);
          const char *name = "OS";
          pid_t pid;
          int shm_fd;
          void *ptr;
```

I call fork

```
pid = fork();
```

The parent process consumes the integers like so

```
                  /* open the shared memory segment */
                  shm_fd = shm_open(name, O_RDONLY, 0666);
                  if (shm_fd == -1) {
                          fprintf(stderr,"open shared memory failed\n");
                          exit(-1);
                  }

                  /* now map the shared memory segment in the address space of the process */
                  ptr = mmap(0,SIZE, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, shm_fd, 0);
                  if (ptr == MAP_FAILED) {
                          fprintf(stderr,"Map failed in parent\n");
                          exit(-1);
                  }
                  printf("Parent got mapped pointer: %p\n",ptr);
                  /* now read from the shared memory region */
                  printf("Parent has received:");
                  for(int i=0; i < SIZE/sizeof(int); i++)
                        printf(" %d ", *(int *)(ptr +i));
                  printf("\n");

                  /* remove the shared memory segment */
                  if (shm_unlink(name) == -1) {
                          fprintf(stderr,"Error removing %s\n",name);
                          exit(-1);
                  }
                  printf("parent done\n");
```

The child produces the integers like so

```
                  printf("In Child process. I am the producer: my pid=%d\n",getpid());
                  time_t t;
                  srand(time(&t));
                  int integers[SIZE];
                  printf("Generating random integers: ");
                  for(int i=0; i < SIZE/sizeof(int); i++){
                          int value = (rand() -49) %49;
                          integers[i] = value;
                          printf(" %d ", value);
                  }
                  printf("\n");


                  /* create the shared memory segment */
                  shm_fd = shm_open(name, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0666);
                  if (shm_fd == -1) {
                          fprintf(stderr,"open shared memory failed\n");
                          exit(-1);
                  }

                  /* configure the size of the shared memory segment */
                  ftruncate(shm_fd,SIZE);

                  /* now map the shared memory segment in the address space of the process */
                  ptr = mmap(0,SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, shm_fd, 0);
                  if (ptr == MAP_FAILED) {
                          fprintf(stderr,"Map failed in child\n");
                          return -1;
                  }
                  printf("Child got mapped pointer: %p\n",ptr);
                  void *ptr2=ptr;//back up the pointer for later use
                  /* Now write to the shared memory region. Increment the value of ptr after each write. */
                  memcpy(ptr, integers, sizeof(int));
                  memcpy(ptr+1,integers+1, sizeof(int));
                  memcpy(ptr+2,integers+2, sizeof(int));
                  memcpy(ptr+3,integers+3, sizeof(int));

                  printf("Child has sent: ");
                  for(int i=0; i < SIZE/sizeof(int); i++)
                          printf(" %d ", *(int *)(ptr2+i));
                  printf("\n");
```

This is a simple consumer-producer IPC program, but for some reason when I run the program my output is incorrect. For example, when I generate a set of integers I get

```
In Parent process. I am the consumer: my child pid=19187
In Child process. I am the producer: my pid=19187
Generating random integers:  8  10  37  48
Child got mapped pointer: 0x7f91c9c09000
Child has sent:  807733768  3155210  12325  48
Parent got mapped pointer: 0x7f91c9c09000
Parent has received: 807733768  3155210  12325  48
parent done
```

It looks like the last memory location is valid, but the first 3 are incorrect. I would very much appreciate any help with this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid there is a typo in pointer arithmetic.
`*(int *)(ptr +i)` should be `*((int *)ptr+i)`
`*(int *)(ptr2+i)` should be `*((int *)ptr2+i)`

It meant *"Increment from `i` bytes then consider as integer pointer"*
instead of
*"consider as integer pointer and increment from `i` elements"*.

There is the same problem with `memcpy(ptr+i,` that should be
`memcpy((int *)ptr+i,`.

An advice: declare immediately `ptr` with the correct type,
this will avoid plenty of dangerous *casts*.

By the way, I cannot see any synchronisation between the child
writing and the parent reading.
Adding an ugly `sleep(1);` (don't do this in real life!)  before
`printf("Parent has received:");` seems to give something correct.

And by another way, depending on the process scheduling, the
`shm_open(name, O_RDONLY, 0666);` call in the parent can fail if the
child has not yet called `shm_open(name, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0666);`
(the segment does not exist yet).

Comment: Thank you. I am still perplexed as to how the last value was printing correctly. However, you were correct. I had a typo in the conversion.

Comment: @EvanGertis writing the second int partially overwrites the first, the third-->the second, the fourth-->the third, but the fourth (the last) is not overwritten. Since the misalignment is the same for both processes, the parent finds the misaligned last int in the exact same state as it was written by the child (the three over ones have been partially overwritten).